# Book about a boy and girl who join a team of people who use robots that are connected through their eyes

Tags: story-identification, novel

I read a book a few years ago. It's about a boy and girl who join a team of people who use robots that are connected through their eyes and when these robots are killed in any way the human is driven insane.

Comment: Can you provide any additional detail? there are quite a few stories about telepresence like that. Do you have any idea what the cover looked like? When was "A few years ago" (your few may not be my few)? Was the book new when you read it? Was it a story in an anthology/collection or a complete novel?

Comment: Your question has been closed for lack of detail, but if you [edit] more details in, it will be flagged to be reopened.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots - It seems fairly findable to me. I count 8 or more pieces of relevant info: It's a published novel, it's from more than a year ago, it features a boy and a girl, said boy and girl join a team of people, these people operate robots, the robots are operated using the person's eyes(?), the user is driven insane if the robot is attacked and dies, and presumably this has happened at least once.

Comment: @Valorum: That is possible. *shrug* I guess I was following the zeitgeist.

Comment: More info would be appreciated, but I’ll vote to reopen

Comment: https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/52459864?

Comment: Welcome to [Science Fiction & Fantasy SE](/tour)! Please consider [registering your account](/users/login), which gives you access to more site features. As a registered user, you will be able to vote, and you won’t lose access to your question if you switch devices or browsers, or when your browser cookies are cleared. [Registering](/users/login) is easy and allows you to participate fully in our community. For more info, see [Why should I register my account?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/44557/162827)

Answer (score 1):

Could it be *BZRK* by Michael Grant?

I’ve also been looking for this book for about a year now. Hopefully, what I know about it will help. I remember reading it 6 or 7 years ago (late middle school, maybe high school), and there were two or three books.

The whole team goes by the aliases of famous people who went insane. The girl goes by the alias "Plath,” and there’s a side character named “Vincent”. At the beginning of the second or third book, a woman goes insane and dies after getting caught in an escalator. I can only remember there being one antagonist, and there’s a part where he takes a shower to try to get the protagonists’ bugs off him.

Comment: The woman got caught in an escalator?  Sounds like she's not particularly resourceful.